# Select sound files in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am very new to Objective C, and I've been searching for an answer to my question, but no luck. I have a game app that plays sounds that I have created, and it plays them randomly with each connection in the gameplay. I would like to create different sound "packs" that the user can select very simply by pressing a button. For example, the user could choose from electric piano, or classical piano, or xylophone, etc. Currently, my sound files are set up as Sound1.wav, Sound2.wav, etc.

What is the best way to approach this? Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: Sounds like you need to consider having them downloaded over the air, otherwise your app size is going to bloat hugely with all the different sound packs you offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably setup a naming convention as such sound_0_1 where the first 0 is pack 0 and 1 is for the first sound in pack 0. These credentials are not exclusive to Objective-C, so any methodology from other programming languages can be applied using their ideals as well.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Do you have any suggestions of how I might structure this?